# How to Compress the WCF service response using GZIP in c#?

Tags: web-services, wcf, gzip, wcf-binding, gzipstream

There is a new requirement where I need to Compress the WCF service response in GZIP format and send it to partner systems in C#. How can I achieve this ?

I have tried adding the configurations in web.config file. But it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I offer you two options:

1.You can use custom bindings to achieve this

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="GzipBinding"> 
    <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/> 
    <httpTransport /> 
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

2.Using **GZip Encoder**, here are the relevant demo documents and examples

[GZip Encoder Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/cc138373(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)